# Quartz.Net using windows task schedular

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I'm looking at having a scheduled task (Console app) that will run every 20 minutes.

I've looked into using Quartz.Net for doing this, and it looks great but I can't see if it will work with my console application.

What I want is:

- If I use only quartz.net then this console application will have to be open forever for my code to be run on schedule. Is there a way where I can have windows run my Quartz.Net scheduled task for me every 20 minutes?

So, Windows Task Schedular --20 mins--> run console app using Quartz.Net.

Or should I make a standard .NET Console App and just have it run the console app every 20 mins?

Cheers

Comment: Use Topshelf (http://topshelf-project.com/) together with Hangfire (http://hangfire.io/) to achieve what you want. Topshelf is an excellent windows service framework, meanwhile hangfire is a scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix Task Scheduler with Quartz they are **2** different methods of doing things.

Normally Task Scheduler is configured at an interval to run Console Applications that just do the work and close.

The suggested way to use **Quartz** is to Embed it in in a windows service application. 
Then install this service on the server and configure it to run always and automatic start (This should protect you from crashes and kills and ensure the application will be running always unlike a console application)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: @magna_nz - To add to this the only way I have seen this in combination is to have a scheduled windows task that periodically starts the windows service (host of Quartz in your case) using `net start` in the case that the service failed (could happen but should not under normal circumstances).